# Though indeed I couldn't try anything, why does my question has to put on hold cruelly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold-questions

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872541/if-a-and-b-are-positive-constants-show-that-fracax-1-fracbx-2) in math SE 2 days ago, which still I'm still trying to solve, but I you can easily see from the comments to the question, some people thought my failure as a lazy person's recklessness. I know in formal question formats in math SE there has to be what you have tried or your own idea about the question but I don't have almost anything for this question, and I flagged the question 2 times but there is not chance in the situation, and now I can't even ask a new question there. So, my question is why people so cruel in math SE, or why the mods doesn't examine carefully the question?

Not: It is my first question on meta. If there is problem about the context, please go easy.

Moreover, after the question put on hold, one of the the previous question is also reported from not having enough context, which had been answered for almost week ago.

Comment: Could at least someone say what is the reason for this down votes ?

Comment: If your post on meta is solely about this particular question, you should probably use ([meta-tag:specific-question]) tag, see the [tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info). If the linked question serves merely as an illustration of a more general issue you want to discuss, you should explain that more clearly in your post.

Comment: It seems relevant enough to mention that the question [had this form](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1872541/2) when it was put on hold. At least it seems so from the [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1872541/revisions).

Comment: Here's what was wrong with your question at the time it was closed: 1) it was stated as an order – you were ordering us to show that the expression had a solution; 2) the part about "supporting your answer with rigorous proof" is the kind of thing a student writes when she wants something she can just copy and hand in as her own work; 3) there was no indication whatever that you had put the least bit of thought into the problem, no indication of where the problem came from, of why it was important to you, of what you knew about the concepts involved, and so on; (continued, next comment)

Comment: (continued) 4) the question doesn't make any sense, since it is *equations* and *problems* that have solutions, not *expressions*. Some of these flaws are still in the current versions of the question. [Also, I don't know what you mean by "I flagged the question two times".]

Comment: You know there is a flag button ? I press  that button :)

Comment: So,you are saying the whole reason that I'm still not have a proper answer for my question, is having said instead of asked, not having said where I took the question and why it is important for me and there is missing "0=" in the equation ?

Comment: Some of your comment (both here and in the linked questions) look like responses to previous comments. You know that if you do not [use @username](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info), then the other user is not notified about your comment, right?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I forgot to add.Thanks for reminding me

Comment: This post on meta mentions several unrelated issues. However, it seems that this older discussion is somewhat related: [Suggested Guideline for “I Don't Know Where to Begin” Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/suggested-guideline-for-i-dont-know-where-to-begin-questions) might be related.

Comment: I'm telling you what (in my opinion) was wrong with your question when it was posted. Note, however, that I wasn't among those who voted to close it. Maybe they had different reasons entirely. And, yes, I know there is a flag button, but usually when someone flags a question, it's to say how bad the question is. That's not what you were doing, so I don't understand what you mean when you say you flagged your own question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I saw in the help centre or in a question on meta math SE says that flag can be used for also in this purpose.

Comment: You might be wondering why did this meta thread received so much negative backlash. And the answer is that people are very allergic to overdramatization on meta. Using "cruel" is just a request to have the meta question downvoted. It's fine to ask why a question was closed, deleted or otherwise mistreated, but it's also very easy to fall into the pit of overdramatization when doing so, which then sets off the downvoting reaction. So next time, try avoiding unnecessary terms like "cruelty". No one here is being cruel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is reopened now. Since I am the one who both voted to close and reopen your question, I may briefly explain my action (though I think the generic comment in the 'off topic' vote is clear enough in this case).

As noted by Gerry in the comment, my vote was cast when the question is still in the first edit. This question should be closed as you did not give any hint what do you know about the question. Do you, for example, know intermediate value theorem? Are you aware that the function is continuous on $(1,2)$? Or, instead you were trying to algebraically solve the equation?

Without knowing the method you used, there is no hint about your background and it is hard to provide an answer for **you**. Also, in some case some users provide an answer which is not comprehensible by the OP, or it is not what they want, the OP might point that out by commenting in the answer or edit the question. This would be a bad experience for both the answer-er (feel like wasting their time) and other users (which saw an answer not answering the question as requested). (Personally there was an user who kept editing their question after seeing my answer, so I have to make four edits to cope with that!)

To me, the best action is to close the question, so that you can add the essential context and other user are not able to provide (potentially) not helpful answer. Personally, I voted to reopen after seeing the term $[1.1,1.9]$ (around edit 4 I guess), since now it is clear that you are aware of the intermediate value theorem and the singularity at $1$ and $2$. The subsequent comment also make it very clear (to me) where you get stuck.

Closing your question is not really that cruel, IMO. The ultimate goal is to help **you** get the better answers.